# Why is the minimum work done not negative in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, work

I was going through my grade 10 physics textbook and noticed that $F S \cos 180^\circ$ (work done will be negative) is less than $F S \cos 90^\circ$ (work done is zero) but it is still stated that $F S \cos 90^\circ$ is the minimum amount of work done. Isn't negative less than zero?

My physics teacher refuses to clear my doubt for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between work done and absolute work done. Work done by one body on another can be negative. If the work done by $A$ on $B$ is negative, say $-W$, then this just means that $B$ does a positive amount of work $W$ on $A$.

For example, a compressed spring $B$ expands and accelerates a block $A$. We can say that $B$ does positive work $W$ on $A$, which increases the kinetic energy of the block *or* we can say that $A$ does negative work $-W$ on $B$, which reduces the potential energy in the spring.

On the other hand, the absolute value of work done, $|W|$, must be greater than or equal to $0$.

In your example, if the work done by one body on the other is $FS \cos \theta$ (and we assume that $F$ and $S$ are positive) then the work done will have a minimum value of $-FS$ when $\theta=180^o$ but the *absolute* work done $FS|\cos \theta|$ will have a minimum value of $0$ when $\theta=\pm90^o$

Answer (score 0):

It should help to go back to basics on this.

An infinitesimal amount of work $\rm{d}W$ is performed by a force $\vec{F}$ on a displacement $\rm{d}\vec{x}$:

[image: Work vector product]

So that:

$$\rm{d}W=\vec{F}\cdot \rm{d}\vec{x}$$

If we assume the vector $\vec{F}$ is constant both in magnitude and direction then we can write with scalars:

$$\rm{d}W=F\cos(\alpha) \rm{d}x$$

Integrated:

$$W=F\cos(\alpha) \Delta x$$

So we get for:

$$\alpha=0^{\circ}\Rightarrow W=F\Delta x$$
$$\alpha=90^{\circ}\Rightarrow W=0$$
$$\alpha=180^{\circ}\Rightarrow W=-F\Delta x$$

Note that the value of $\Delta x$ can be positive, negative or zero.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\mathrm{d} W = \vec F \color{red}{\cdot} \mathrm{d}\vec x$?

Comment: @NiharKarve Yup. Didn't know the Latex for that one, so I improvised. Thanks.

Comment: Another MathJax tip: try using \mathrm instead of \rm, I think you'll get the formatting for the differentials that you wanted (currently even the subsequent variables are in roman, due to using \rm in math code)

Comment: While this is all true, it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @NiharKarve That's what I used to use but what a slog compared to rm...